# How to change a class inside jasper jar file

Tags: java

I'm facing some issues with jasper and I need to try to edit SmapUtil class inside jasper.jar file

However, I'm facing some problems to do so.

I've used jd-gui to decompile the jasper.jar file, took out the SmapUtil.java file, changed the 
install method from

```html
    static void install(File classFile, byte[] smap) throws IOException {
      File tmpFile = new File(classFile.getPath() + "tmp");
      SDEInstaller installer = new SDEInstaller(classFile, smap);
      installer.install(tmpFile);
      if (!classFile.delete()) {
        throw new IOException("classFile.delete() failed");
      }
      if (!tmpFile.renameTo(classFile)) {
        throw new IOException("tmpFile.renameTo(classFile) failed");
      }
    }
```

to

```html
 static void install(File classFile, byte[] smap){
      File tmpFile = new File(classFile.getPath() + "tmp");
      SDEInstaller installer = new SDEInstaller(classFile, smap);
      installer.install(tmpFile);
      while (!classFile.delete());
      while (!tmpFile.renameTo(classFile));
    }
```

it's basically to keep trying to delete the file if it doens't work the first time.

Now it's where I'm facing my problem.

If I try to compile SmapUtil.java, I face a lot of missing sources.
I've tried using javac -classpath (original)jasper.jar SmapUtil.java, but I still have a lot of sources missings.

I've downloaded a jasper-sources.jar file from god knows where and used that as a -classpath, but the missing sources remains..

How should I do that? I don't think that it should that hard to change 2 lines of a file inside a jar..

Thankss

Comment: it was solved by recompiling it and changing the code
from something like

```java
    if ( !classPath.delete(..) )
      throw Exception...
```

to something like:

```java
    while ( !classPath.delete(..) && count < 10){
      Thread.wait(50);
      count++
    }

    if (count == 10) 
         Throw Exception
```

Comment: worth creating a bug report somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling a large project such as Tomcat can be a fairly complicated endeavour. If you try decompiling/editing/recompiling without knowing this process you will probably run into a lot of issues.

It might easier (or at least predictable) to build the entire project from sources. Once you have managed to build it, you can try editing the sources.

You should be able to checkout the sources from [the project's website](https://tomcat.apache.org/source.html).

If you need to patch this class because you feel it's not working correctly, it might be worth trying submitting a bugreport

Comment: thanks, I'll try to follow your hints;;;;;;

just a quick question, is it possible to develop (or there's something already) to use the compiled class as kind of a "source" to re-build the class
If you have already a compiled class, how hard is to use those references to change the class and re-use those reference?
(assuming that the references are stored in the class file somehow), like a link or so

Comment: It is possible in principle to use decompiled classes and recompile them, however as you've noticed these will usually have external dependencies/prerequisites. So pretty quickly you need to replicate the project's build process to recompile

Comment: why isn't possible to re-compile a class using only the previous .class file of that 
class as a "dependency", as the previous compile class already "knows everything it needs to know"

Comment: Well, you should be able to edit the bytecode in the .class file yourself but that's not how compiler typically work. What if you're introducing a new dependency? Or calling a method that was not called in the original .class file?

Comment: I'll try to do that @Guillaume, all I need to do is delete e exception throw and change 2 if's to while's (busy wait)

Comment: thanks, I fixed it by re-compiling the entire project (really easier :b)